# How should I use ezANOVA() if I already collapsed the data to cell means?

Tags: r, anova

I want to do a repeated measures ANOVA using ezANOVA() from the ez pacakge. My experimental designs is a two-way repeated measures design: soa (which has four levels) X congruency (which has three levels), and the data bellow is organized according to the above order (i.e., soa x congruency), with "subject" being the ID column.
My question is how should I use ezANOVA() if I already collapsed the data to cell means (the data bellow is after I collapsed the dependent variables for each subject according to soa x congruency)?

```
subject mrt1    mrt2    mrt3    mrt4    mrt5    mrt6    mrt7    mrt8    mrt9    mrt10   mrt11   mrt12
99  1039.3  1078.1176   997.5323    873.4615    1024    916.2   1061.0909   1008.7778   919.7879    1053    1052.9615   953.619
5203    1020.4545   1098.6667   911.2642    941.25  944.2857    976.1053    949 992.4167    870.4308    783.9091    852.1176    927.8852
5205    1373.7273   1074.2143   986.7397    1193.4615   1031.9545   1108.4789   1041.2727   1036.0625   989.0714    1180.5  908.9688    944.2024
5306    1012.375    1038.8421   949.4938    1320    1213.5714   1003.3133   1027.3333   970.2778    922.3939    1102    971.4286    943.5634
5307    1397.8333   1243.4  1114    1038    1187.6  1046.2588   1121.4  1376.0833   1080.6615   1075.2727   1159.2381   1060.6818
5308    809.9091    1193.75 1061.2895   923.7647    1128.4286   959.5783    771 1499.25 998.875 925.8462    1074.4  1022.3418
5309    1185    1257.2857   1230.1  1231.8333   1167.4545   1197.2051   1332.4444   1323.9  1334.359    1331.6  1418.5714   1198.8378
5410    1093.7  1154.2778   991.0147    1238.3846   1040.4783   1010.2  1009.3636   1161.6  1016.0946   1140.25 1020.1481   986.5312
5511    881.8182    1082.2  752.5455    1119.2222   969.25  848.8602    958.9444    850.3448    805.75  860.3   902.1579    758.1875
5512    879 1039    951.9138    866.4545    1146.7  898.2841    988 1078.3214   911.4203    1365.7273   1179    924.4928
5513    1239.3333   1063.9565   1013.1111   1018.25 1244.5625   1091.0847   1031.6667   1035.2381   1035.8727   1013.25 1016.5238   1045.9444
5614    1151.5385   1044.4545   1050.5303   1046.2727   1116.1154   1037.9577   1080.7647   1192.1053   1054.9688   1100    995.625 1065.1408
5715    1432    1307.1765   1152.6087   1124.7778   1305.9091   1125.7792   1210.5  1268.7647   1167.8  1199.5  1137.0476   1115.8462
5716    996.7143    1355    1108.4231   1026.8  1251.4286   1108.3333   1130.2857   1196.5333   1071    919.4545    1183.4286   1040.9796
5817    1046.9  1075.8276   865.7534    1058.1818   1101.9259   877.2143    923.5   1063.25 880.44  1050.2  984.24  919.8913
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated,

Ayala

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @docendodiscimus thanks! I published my question there.

Comment: Are both factors "within-subjects"?

Comment: @user3143179. Yes, both factors are within-subjects.

Comment: @user3143179. Thanks! But I like to do the ANOVA on my aggregated data.